# How to group list with index wise?

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I have a list of list where i need to group elements by using user input ( see `split` variable in code ) and create new list.
I have tried but instead of grouping, elements are concatenated separately

```
split = 3 # user input 
data = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8], [9,10], [11,12], [13,14], [15,16], [17,18]]
z = [] ; y = []
for i,d in enumerate(data):
    z.append(d)
    if (i+1)%split==0:
        y.append(z)
        z = []
xx = (y+[z])
print(xx)
[[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], [[7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]], [[13, 14], [15, 16], [17, 18]], []]
# ^____________________^    ^_______________________^  this needs to be merged
```

input :

```
data = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8], [9,10], [11,12], [13,14], [15,16], [17,18]]
```

expected output :

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way using list comprehension:

```
>>> sp = 3
>>> fragment = len(data)//sp
>>> [[t for item in data[i:i+fragment] for t in item] for i in range(0, len(data), fragment)]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]]
```

And here is an intertools based recipe:

```
>>> from itertools import islice, chain
>>> 
>>> [list(chain.from_iterable(islice(data, i, i+fragment))) for i in range(0, len(data), fragment)]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in basic Python like this:

```
import itertools
flatlist = [*itertools.chain(*data)]
groupsize = int(len(flatlist) / split)

data2 = [flatlist[i:i+groupsize] for i in range(0, len(flatlist), groupsize)]
print(data2)
```

And the output is

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using numpy:

```
data = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8], [9,10], [11,12], [13,14], [15,16], [17,18]]
import numpy as np
print np.array(data).reshape((split,-1)).tolist()
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this ->

```
split = 3
data = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8], [9,10], [11,12], [13,14], [15,16], [17,18]]
z=[]
x=[]
for i,j in enumerate(data):
    if i!=0 and i%split==0: 
        z.append(x)
        x=[]
    for k in j:
        x.append(k)
z.append(x)
print z
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use `z.extend(d)` instead of `append`